# Screen size in openSUSE 13.2 in VirtualBox 5.0.26

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse

After a system update the virtual screen of my openSUSE is not getting automatically adjusted. That is, the "Auto-resize Guest Display" is grey.

I have tried to install virtualBox addition using zipper:

```
$ sudo zipper in virtualbox-guest-kmp-default virtualbox-guest-tools virtualbox-guest-x11
```

And did not corrected it.

I have also tried to install the addition using the virtual CD and it did not correct it either.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved installing the `virtualbox-guest-kmp-desktop` instead of the `virtualbox-guest-kmp-default`, but before installing the new package I had to uninstall completely the old ones. So the steps were:

```
$ sudo rpm -e --nodeps --allmatches virtualbox-guest-kmp-desktop
$ sudo rpm -e --nodeps --allmatches virtualbox-guest-kmp-default
$ sudo zipper in virtualbox-guest-kmp-desktop
```